# Cannot resolve implemented object while using generic type in asp.net .core

Tags: generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

My problem is simple!
How can I resolve manually this registered interface:

```
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<Command>, AddProductCommandHandler>();
```

This code not work and always return `null`:

My `DiContainer` is like this:

```
public class ProviderDiContainer : IDiContainer
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider _container;

    public ProviderDiContainer(ServiceProvider container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {        
       return _container.GetService<T>();
    }
}
```

Which is registered such:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    var diContainer = new ProviderDiContainer(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    services.AddSingleton<IDiContainer>(c => diContainer);
//  Register some other things here      Registrar.RegisterSomethings(services);
    services.AddSingleton(s => new ServiceLocator(diContainer));
}
```

And my Service Locator is:

```
public class ServiceLocator
{
    public ServiceLocator(IDiContainer container)
    {
            Current = container;
    }

    public static IDiContainer Current
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Now when I call this code it returns `null` to me:

```
var commandHandler = ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
```

**Note**: To resolve `ServiceLocator` and `DbiContainer` at first, I put them in `Configure` method of the StartUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **that' because you're building an another `ServiceProvider` which is different from the default one** . Note the following code :

`var diContainer = new ProviderDiContainer(services.BuildServiceProvider());` .

That means the you'll use the services collection to build a new `ServiceProvider`, and then pass that `ServiceProvider` to `ProviderDiContainer`. **As a result, any services registered below that line will not be resolved by the `ProviderDiContainer`.**

**How to fix**

1. Instead of asking for a specific implementation, we should depends on abstraction (interface):

```
    public class ProviderDiContainer: IDiContainer {

        private readonly ServiceProvider _container; 
        private readonly IServiceProvider _container;

        public ProviderDiContainer(ServiceProvider container) 
        public ProviderDiContainer(IServiceProvider container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public T Resolve<T>()
        {        
            return _container.GetService<T>();
        }
    }
```

2. Don't build unnecessary `ServiceProvider`:

```
    var diContainer = new ProviderDiContainer(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    services.AddSingleton<IDiContainer>(c => diContainer);
     ... 
    services.AddSingleton(s => new ServiceLocator(diContainer));
    services.AddSingleton<IDiContainer>(sp => new ProviderDiContainer(sp));
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceLocator>();
```

Comment: Thanks! The gold key was `sp => new ProviderDiContainer(sp)`. I thought that `BuildServiceProvider` returns the current provider.