# How to access a service in ASP.NET Core before building the WebHost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's assume that we have the following `Program.cs`:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureKestrel(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = false; })
            .ConfigureFanciness()
            .ConfigureLogging(ConfigureApplicationLogging)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    private static void ConfigureApplicationLogging(WebHostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
    {
        var loggingConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");

        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(loggingConfiguration);

        // var fancyService = SomehowGet<IFancyService>();
        // if (fancyService.IsEnabled)
        //     loggingBuilder.AddEventLog(loggingConfiguration);
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureFanciness(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(delegate (WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var fancinessConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Fanciness");
            services.Configure<FancinessSettings>(fancinessConfiguration);
            services.AddSingleton<IFancyService, FancyService>();

            // var fancyService = SomehowGet<IFancyService>();
            // fancyService.Initialize();
        });
    }
}
```

And the following `FancyService.cs`:

```cs
public sealed class FancyService : IFancyService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FancyService> logger;
    private readonly IOptions<FancinessSettings> settings;

    public FancyService(ILogger<FancyService> logger, IOptions<FancinessSettings> settings)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; private set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // do the initialization work and set IsEnabled to some value
    }
}
```

As demonstrated in the example files, `loggingBuilder.AddEventLog(loggingConfiguration)` depends on `IFancyService.IsEnabled` that is set when `IFancyService.Initialize()` is called.

To do that, I need access to an instance of `IFancyService`; is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think more context as to what this service is doing and what initialise does, is required as for me, I can see a few ways of doing this, but it depends on the service.   Is it not possible to register the initialisation in the constructor?

Comment: Some how it feels reversed although am not sure of the purpose to comment so, may i know what is the purpose of `isEnabled`?

Comment: Although it's possible to reference the `IFancyService` before actually building the `WebHost`, I don't think your code has a good design: Your `IFancyService` requires a `ILogger<>` service, and a `ILogger<>` service requires a `ILoggerFactory` service  which uses `ILoggerProvider` & other options to create such an instance. It works fine for the present. But if you  want to configure the logging behavior according to the `IFancySerivce.IsEnabled`, it will finally introduce a **Circular Dependency**.

Comment: @KieranDevlin, @Jaya, can you help me understand why it is important to know the details of what `Initialize()` do and what `IsEnabled` is? You can imagine the former as an work that I don't want to do in a constructor, like reading a file from disk or data from the network, and the former as the result of the processing the data in the file or the stream. Yes, it is possible to register an initialised `FancyService`, but then I need to manually create its dependencies, the `ILogger<FancyService>` and the `IOptions<FancinessSettings>`.

Comment: @itminus, I'm aware of what looks like as a circular dependency. However, in this case `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` already configures the default loggers and `ConfigureApplicationLogging()` just adds more if `IFancySerivce.IsEnabled`. Anyway, if you have a better idea to achieve what I'm try to do, please let me know.

Comment: what does by `ConfigureApplicationLogging() ` behind the scenes is adding more logging-related services. I'm not sure why you have a `IFancyService.IsEnabled` dependency . Is that a dynamic property or a option-configured property? Maybe using the `FancinessSettings.IsEnabled` if possible?

Comment: @itminus, `IsEnabled` isn't a static configuration; it's the result of processing a file. I used a boolean property for simplicity (or so I thought), but it's actually multiple properties that I need to evaluate. These properties are the result of processing a file.

Comment: @TheBlueSky So if I understand correctly, the `IFancyService.IsEnabled` must be evaluated before the WebHost is created. And the `IFancySerivce` instance must be created before the WebHost is build. But you won't get a `ILogger<>` until the `ServiceCollection` is built into `ServiceProvider`. I believe need remove the `ILogger<>` dependency within the constructor of `FancyService`.

Comment: @itminus, probably. Let's assume `ILogger<>` dependency is not there, that does not solve my problem; I still need an instance of `IFancyService` in both the methods.

Comment: @TheBlueSky If your IFancyService has no `ILogger<>` dependency, it's possible to reference the service before we create it. If you're interested, I'll write some code and test it

Comment: @TheBlueSky Can you please add the whole class file of `FancyService` so we can make our own judgement.

Comment: @KieranDevlin, can you see my reply to @itminus earlier? Unfortunately, I cannot put the implementation here, but in short, you can think about `Initialize()` (the important part of the class) simply as reading some data (from network, file, API, etc.), process it, and set the value of `IsEnabled`. It is not only a configuration you can read from `appsettings.json`, for example.

Comment: @itminus, yes, I'm interested.

Comment: Without the code I cannot help you. We will just continue down a rabbit hole of me asking a question on what  `x` does and then you reply with `y` and then I have to ask a question about `y`. If the code is commercially sensitive then try pseudo it out so we can get a detailed but abstract understanding of what this whole service is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Once `services.AddSingleton<IFancyService, FancyService>()` has been called, you can get the instance of `FancyService` by building a `ServiceProvider`:

```
private static void ConfigureApplicationLogging(WebHostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    var fancyService = loggingBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IFancyService>();
    fancyService.Initialize();
    var loggingConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");

    loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(loggingConfiguration);

    if (fancyService.IsEnabled)
        loggingBuilder.AddEventLog(loggingConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: What about in `ConfigureApplicationLogging()`?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, if your `FancyService` has no constructor dependency on `ILogger<>` :

```
public sealed class FancyService : IFancyService
{ 
    public FancyService(IOptions<FancinessSettings> settings)
    { ... }
```

to initialize the `IFancyService`, simply use an **implementation factory** to create a `IFancyService` instance:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureFanciness(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(delegate (WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var fancinessConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Fanciness");
        services.Configure<FancinessSettings>(fancinessConfiguration);
        services.AddSingleton<IFancyService, FancyService>(sp =>{
            var fancy=ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(sp,typeof(FancyService)) as FancyService;
            fancy.Initialize();      
            return fancy;
        });
    });
}
```

The same trick could also be used to register a logger provider. Since an `ILogger<>` service depends on `IEnumerable<ILoggerProvider>`, we could register an `ILoggerProvider` instance that provides an additional `INullLogger` in order to configure the logging behavior according to the current `IFancyService` :

```cs
private static void ConfigureApplicationLogging(WebHostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    var loggingConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");

    var descriptor=ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider,NullLoggerProvider>(sp =>{
        var provider = NullLoggerProvider.Instance;
        var fancy = sp.GetRequiredService<IFancyService>();
        if(fancy.IsEnabled)      
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            loggingBuilder.AddEventLog(loggingConfiguration);
            loggingBuilder.AddEventSourceLogger(); 
            // ... add more configuration as you like
        }else{
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        }
        return provider;
    });
    loggingBuilder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(descriptor);
    loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(loggingConfiguration);
}
```

As a side note, be aware once the logger has been built, don't change the `IFancyService.IsEnabled`. That's because the `ILogger<>` service is a registered as a singleton and never changed once created.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unclear, though, about why doing it this way compared to using `loggingBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IFancyService>();` as suggested in @AlliterativeAlice answer.

Comment: @TheBlueSky There's a recent similar thread asking a similar question. See [poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348625/use-instance-of-service-in-configure-services-method/56351537#56351537) . In addition, different service provider introduce different service as well as scopes. You must be very careful when dealing this.

Comment: @TheBlueSky Also, there was a bug caused by multiple service providers  , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922206/cannot-resolve-implemented-object-while-using-generic-type-in-asp-net-core/53926893#53926893