# .net core 3 dependency injecting services as parameters to 'configure'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've just upgraded a .net core app from version 2.2 to 3.
Inside the ConfigureServices method in startup.cs I need to resolve a service that is used by the authentication service.
I was "building" all the services using "services.BuildServiceProvider()" but .net core 3 complains about the method creating additional copies of the services and suggesting me to dependency injecting services as parameters to 'configure'.
I have no idea what the suggestion means and I'd like to understand it.

```cs
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Need to resolve this.
    services.AddSingleton<IManageJwtAuthentication, JwtAuthenticationManager>();

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider(); // COMPLAINING HERE!!
    var jwtAuthManager = sp.GetRequiredService<IManageJwtAuthentication>();

    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(c =>
        {
            c.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                AudienceValidator = jwtAuthManager.AudienceValidator,
                // More code here...
            };
        }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but .net core 3 complains about the method creating additional copies of the services and suggesting me to dependency injecting services as parameters to 'configure'.

Actually, the `ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()` should be invoked by the Host **automatically**. Your code `services.BuildServiceProvider();` will create a **duplicated** service provider that is **different** the default one, which might lead to **inconsistent** service states. See [a bug caused by multiple Service Provider here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922206/cannot-resolve-implemented-object-while-using-generic-type-in-asp-net-core/53926893#53926893).

To solve this question, [**configure the options with dependency injection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1) instead of creating a service provider and then locating a service.

For your codes, rewrite them as below:

```
services.AddSingleton<IManageJwtAuthentication, JwtAuthenticationManager>();

services.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Configure<IManageJwtAuthentication>((opts,jwtAuthManager)=>{
        opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            AudienceValidator = jwtAuthManager.AudienceValidator,
            // More code here...
        };
    });

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer();
```

Comment: So basically when it "runs" the Authentication service it injects the jwtAuthManager service into the options?

Comment: @LucaMarangon There're will be a singleton `AuthenticationSchemeOptions`(e.g. JwtBearerOptions) for particular authentication handler(e.g. JwtBearerHandler). We can configure it by `AddScheme<>(action)` (e.g. AddJwtBearer(action)) , or configure the options by a options builder so that we can inject the service without building the service provider. In that case, your jwtAuthManager service is invoked whenever your authentication service invoked.