# .net core DI injection duplicated singleton service for BuildServiceProvide

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to remove duplicated singleton service for BuildServiceProvider method. I understand I should use the existing DI service but I can't access the GetService method. I am new to DI and I appreciate it if someone could say how to access the GetService method without getting new service. Code below. Thanks.

MESSAGE: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();//CODE ISSUE HERE
        var permissionService = sp.GetService<IPermissionService>();
        if (permissionService != null)
        {
          foreach (var permission in permissionService.GetPrivilegePermissions().Select(x => x.Name)
                   .Distinct())
          {

            options.AddPolicy(permission, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new 
 PermissionRequirement(permission)));

          }

        }

      });

 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written a lambda method to configure an object. However, since all Microsoft services follow the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) pattern, you could instead write a service to configure it. Injecting any other service you want. You may implement any number of `IConfigureOptions<T>` services for any options type.

```cs
public class ConfigureAuthorization : IConfigureOptions<AuthorizationOptions>{
    public ConfigureAuthorization( ... ){}

    public void Configure(AuthorizationOptions options){
        // ...
    }
}

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<AuthorizationOptions>, ConfigureAuthorization>();
```

Note, beware of any potential [scoping](https://andrewlock.net/the-dangers-and-gotchas-of-using-scoped-services-when-configuring-options-in-asp-net-core/) issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think I'm following your code correctly. This is on the Startup page where I have both ConfigureServices and Configure methods registering a bunch of other services using options patter. How does this fit in the existing code? I have tried writing a secondary class  ConfigureAuthorization couldn't get it to work.Was hoping for something like this-  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212736/net-core-3-dependency-injecting-services-as-parameters-to-configure) - to stay inside the ConfigureService method.

Comment: I don't think you can define a class inside a method. But you can define one class inside another, or multiple classes side-by-side in the same file.