# What is the best way to move .NET 6 CORE Authorization Policies out of program.cs for a clean program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have lots of Authorization Policies in my .NET 6 CORE project. Right now my program.cs file (.NET 6 - Does not have startup.cs) is cluttered with lots of policies is there a way I can clean up program.cs file and move all the policies code to a different class or file in .NET CORE 6?

Please let me know if any additional details are required.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SuperAdminPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Super Administrator"));

    options.AddPolicy("DashboardPolicy", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.IsInRole("Super Administrator") ||
            context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type=="Dashboard" && claim.Value=="true")));

    options.AddPolicy("CreateRolePolicy", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        context.User.IsInRole("Super Administrator") ||
        context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Create Role" && claim.Value == "true"));
        
    // ... And so many more policies as this
    
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

I did find many articles on how to do this in earlier versions of .NET Core. I,am not sure how to go about this in .NET 6 Core. As per below comment extension methods look promising. But .NET 6 has a very simple program.cs file there are key differences in the implementation.

Comment: Extension method on `AuthorizationOptions`? Then you could have something like `options.AddMyCustomPolicies();` or register an `IConfigureOptions<AuthorizationOptions>`?

Comment: @Llama I,m not sure how I can extent AuthorizationOptions in .net 6. Could you please elaborate

Comment: I would use a #region :D

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925761/net-core-di-injection-duplicated-singleton-service-for-buildserviceprovide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using custom policies and Handlers as per above comments following the steps described in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXsYer31UPo&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVkdrusLaQsfERmL_Jh4XmU&index=101

1. Create Custom Authorization Policies
2. Create Handlers as needed for the policy requirements.
3. Register the services in program.cs